# Convert scalar variable and its value to hash ref variable's value

Tags: perl

Trying to understand why the following does not work:

```
DB<1> $record = "some value"
DB<2> $record->{default} = $record;
DB<3> use Data::Dumper
```

Would think `Dumper` should show same results as **step 10**:

```
DB<4> print Dumper $record
$VAR1 = 'some value';

DB<5> $temp = $record
DB<6> $record->{default} = $temp
```

At least in this case, would surly think `Dumper` would show results as **step 10**:

```
DB<7> print Dumper $record
$VAR1 = 'some value';
```

Do you really need to force it ?

```
DB<8> undef $record
DB<9> $record->{default} = $temp
DB<10> print Dumper $record
$VAR1 = {
          'default' => 'some value'
        };
```

How can I understand/explain why Perl does not "get" what I mean to do?

Comment: you don't need to do ``use Data::Dumper`` in the debugger, there is a command x that does Dumper() built in

Comment: I don't "get" what you mean to do.

Comment: Unless you have a specific issue with the debugger, it's much better to write a Perl script file that shows the problematic behaviour. You're reducing your audience because a substantial number of programmers aren't au fait with the debugger, and even those who know it well would rather not have the noise to contend with on top of the real question

Comment: No, I did not need the debugger, I used it just as a tool to see/prove my work. Yes, I should have just posted as a script and not as my debugging step... But, hey, it was worth it to know about the `x` command. Though the output it's not same as `Data::Dumper`

Comment: @lzc: All of the debugger commands are documented—albeit tersely—in its command line documentation. If you run `perl -de0` then `h` will show you the list of commands. `p` and `x` behave similarly to `print` and `print Dumper` respectively, and there is also `m` which will list all of the currently-loaded methods of a given object. You should experiment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And this is why you need to `use strict;` `use warnings;`.

Because if so - what you do, generates an error that tells you the problem:

```
Can't use string ("some value") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"
```

What you are specifically trying to do is:

```
"some value" -> {default} = "some value";
```

Which just doesn't make sense, because you're trying to dereference a string value.

Comment: In fact, without `strict refs`, it's somehow possible (see my answer). But I wouldn't advice anyone to do it.

Answer (score 7):

The process of creating a hash or array when needed is called **autovivification**. Only an undefined value can be autovivified.

Note that without [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) `refs`, the following works:

```
my $record = 'some value';
$record->{default} = 'other value';
print $record, $record->{default};
```

because Perl autovivifies a variable called "some value" for you, as you can verify:

```
print ${'some value'}{default};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $record = 'some value';
$record = { default => $record };
```

Perl is a typed language (although the types are scalar, list, hash, rather than integer, float, etc). When you first assign to `$record`, it becomes a simple scalar.

Then, when `perl` encounters `$record->{default}`, it realizes you are trying to treat this simple scalar as a reference to a hash.

On the other hand, with `$record = { default => $record }`, you create a new anonymous hash, and assign a reference to it to `$record`, over-writing what `$record` held before.

Perl now knows that `$record` holds a reference to an anonymous hash.